# Can't define the size of a shared memory object

Tags: c, unix, posix, shared-memory

Hello I'm trying to create a shared memory object using POSIX functions but I'm getting a weird error.

// Create shared memory

```
if( (shmid = shm_open("/OS",   O_CREAT ,0700)) == -1){
    printf("Error creating memory\n");
    exit(1);
}
printf("shmid: %d\n", shmid);

if (ftruncate(shmid, sizeof(int)) == -1){
    printf("Error defining size\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

As you can imagine it keeps printing out "Error defining size".
The value printed out by shmid is 3, a valid value. Yet the ftruncate() functions returns -1 because of an error... the value set to errno is 22 which as I have seen on the internet is due to "invalid arguments" but I don't understand why.... suggestions?

Comment: Under the System V IPC (which I know you're not using), there is a minimum size of a shared memory segment as a kernel configuration parameter.  Maybe that is applied to POSIX shared memory too, and maybe `sizeof(int)` is too small.  Have you tried printing the error number from `ftruncate()` (using `perror()`, or `errno` and `strerror()`, or …)?  You've tagged the question with the [tag:unix] tag which suggests maybe you aren't using Linux; which platform are you running on?

Comment: Yes!I've printed out errno and it returns 22 as I said. According to what I've read, before using ftruncate() the size is set to 0 bytes, and sizeof(int) should be 4 bytes.

Comment: I missed that — check that 22 is EINVAL in your /usr/include/sys/errno.h (it quite likely is; or use `perror()` to give you the appropriate error message).  There are two possibilities when you get EINVAL from `ftruncate()` — either the `shmid` is wrong or the size is wrong.  Since you check the `shmid` and it looks correct, that most likely means the size is wrong.

Comment: On my system, `22` is `EINVAL`. On my system, that means "*The argument length is negative or larger than the maximum file size.*" (according to `man ftruncate`). That may not be an exhaustive description of the conditions that lead to that error. What is the current size of the file?

Comment: Okay, as I expected, perror prints out Invalid argument... But if you think the size is wrong, then what should it be? I just want to store an integer, that's why I wrote sizeof(int)

Comment: I don't know — I suggest trying 1 KiB (1024 bytes) as a size and see whether anything changes.  Or work out how to find the shared memory configuration parameters on your system — how to do that varies by system.  The other alternative, which is very implausible, is that `sizeof(int)` is too large; you could try a size of `1`, but I would expect the EINVAL error.

Comment: Should you specify `O_RDWR | O_CREAT` for `shm_open`? The documentation of `ftruncate` at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/ftruncate.html lists "[EBADF] or [EINVAL] The fildes argument is not a file descriptor open for writing." or "[EINVAL] The fildes argument references a file that was opened without write permission."

Comment: Good point, @Bodo — but if the absence of both O_RDONLY and O_RDWR (one of which is mandatory according to [`shm_open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shm_open.html)) matters, then the `shm_open()` call should fail.  Of course, if one of O_RDONLY or O_RDWR is zero (and O_RDONLY might well be), then it could be that a process cannot extend a read-only shared memory segment — only a process that opened the shared memory segment with O_RDWR mode can do that.  It makes sense (at least, after a fashion).

Comment: I'm running VM with LUbuntu
I've tried to specify O_RDWR with shm_open but it gives a Seg fault error becuse O_RDWR opens a file, but there is no file yet, so I can only use O_CEAT I think.
I've tried to give 1024 as an argument but it works the same. sizeof(int) is 4 bytes, it would be really weird if that's too large...

Comment: Okay I figured it out! I have to specify both O_CREAT and O_RDWR but it has to be in this specific order! Thank you for your help guys, it really helped!

Comment: @SnepyTribos Of course you have to specify `O_RDWR | O_CREAT`. It doesn't have to be in a specific order as bitwise or is commutative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `errno` value of `22` on a Linux system is `EINVAL`. Instead of showing the number value you should use `perror` or `strerror(errno)` to get a text error message like "Invalid argument".

Use

```
if ((shmid = shm_open("/OS", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0700)) == -1){
```

The POSIX documentation for [`ftruncate()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ftruncate.html) lists:

> `[EBADF]` or `[EINVAL]` —
>       The fildes argument is not a file descriptor open for writing.

and

> `[EINVAL]` —
>       The fildes argument references a file that was opened without write permission.

The Linux man page at https://linux.die.net/man/2/ftruncate states

> `EBADF` or `EINVAL` —
>       fd is not open for writing.